# Problems using graphviz as a library

Tags: c, gcc, graphviz

I'm trying to use graphviz as a library for a C++ project, following the [libguide](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/libguide/libguide.pdf) provided here. However I'm having problems even compiling the examples in the appendix. When I try to compile demo.c using gcc I get the following output:

```
$ gcc -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.28.0/include/ demo.c -L/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.28.0/lib/ -lgvc -lgraph -lcdt
demo.c: In function ‘main’:
demo.c:14: error: ‘Agdirected’ undeclared (first use in this function)
demo.c:14: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
demo.c:14: error: for each function it appears in.)
demo.c:15: error: too many arguments to function ‘agnode’
demo.c:16: error: too many arguments to function ‘agnode’
demo.c:17: error: too many arguments to function ‘agedge’
```

Agdirected is found in cgraph.h, but if I change the includes in demo.c to

```
#include <graphviz/gvc.h>
#include <graphviz/cgraph.h>
```

Then all hell breaks loose (mostly conflicting declarations between the two headers). How can I include the necessary headers without the headache of all these conflicts?

Mac OS X 10.8.3, Graphviz 2.28.0, GCC 4.2.1

Comment: It seems that gvc.h includes types.h, which includes cgraph.h, so I'm at a loss as for why it thinks that Agdirected is undeclared.

Answer (score 2):

The libguide you are using is the cgraph version, which assumes Graphviz 2.30 or later. With that version, the #define WITH_CGRAPH is already provided.

Answer (score 1):

It seems after some experimentation that adding the flag

```
#define WITH_CGRAPH
```

has the effect of including cgraph.h, which gets rid of the "'Agdirected' undeclared" error.

The other errors can be fixed by changing the command line option in gcc from -lgraph to -lcgraph